# Nib Navigation Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

I have a button in my ProfileView view controller nib called that when pressed I went to display the OptionsView view controller.

In my ProfileView.m file I have this is viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options"     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(actionOptions)];
```

and then I have:

```
- (void)actionOptions
{
    OptionsView *screen = [[OptionsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsView" bundle:Nil];
  [self.view addSubview:screen.view];
}
```

But whenever I tap the button I get a Thread 1: signal **SIGABRT** with the following console output:

```
2014-11-24 13:43:54.107 app[2161:5537921] didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo=0x7ff7c2c365d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
2014-11-24 13:43:55.673 app[2161:5537921] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:7344
2014-11-24 13:43:55.676 app[2161:5537921] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Comment: Why can't you just link the button to an IBAction in the nib?

Comment: I get the same error when I do that

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you posted.  Did you read the console output you posted?

Comment: As @stromdotcom said. My guess is that the problem is with the code of `OptionsView` view controller. You are probably not implementing the `UITableViewDataSourceDelegate` correctly, and therefore, whenever this viewController gets called, your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have SIGABRT because datasource of tableview that displayed in OptionsView is not returning valid cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. 
Code that you are posted is OK.